# What happens during an iPhone restore

Tags: ios, itunes, downgrade

I'm looking at the apticket system and capturing TSS data. I want to know all the steps in restoring and verifying the IPSW, and exactly what data is sent to the signing server. From what I understand, the steps are as follows.

```
IPSW downloaded
Device ECID, iOS version and a 'nonce' sent to iTunes server
Above info signed, along with a hash of the IPSW (to create an apticket), and sent back to the client
Apticket verified by bootloader (hard wired into device)
```

Is this correct, what format does an apticket take, is any other information used, and how is the 'nonce' generated?

Comment: Do you have charles proxy or another tool or are you asking us how you might set that sort of snooping mechanism up?

Comment: I'm wondering if someone has already done something like that and knows what actually happens

Comment: Hopefully those will be the people that make an answer as opposed to people that just think about it or wish to convince you of doing something else ;-)

Comment: Do you consider this question unanswered?

Comment: By the way, the "way to do things" around here is to [accept the answer that helped you the most](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). I have updated my answer reflecting my statement about the bootloaders.

Comment: Sorry. Answer deleted; answer accepted. I didn't mean to steal your answer, I just couldn't mark a comment as a correct answer. Thank you

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could point you in the right direction on iOS firmware restores!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically correct. Information about the [APTicket can be found here](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/APTicket), and [SHSH information can be found here](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/SHSH_Protocol). And [here is a slideshow](https://t.co/0X5PVGo4) from [iH8sn0w](https://twitter.com/iH8sn0w) from [JailbreakCon](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/JailbreakCon) in 2012 that describes everything else that you could ever want to know about the process. The JailbreakCon link has a list of all talks and links to their videos and/or slides (if publicly available) should you be hungry for even more information.

As far as actually *how* the nonce is generated, the bootloaders have been dumped, but they're proprietary and protected by copyright law, so publishing their contents is illegal. You can, however, [dump them yourself](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/IBoot_%28Bootloader%29#Extract_and_Disassemble), and investigate on your own.

Comment: What is the PRNG inside the iPhone bootloader based on? Why hasn't anyone managed to decompile the PRNG? Has Apple really put all the money for a true RNG in the iPhone bootloader just to prevent downgrades?