# "iTunes will erase and restore your iPad to iOS 8.4.1 and will verify the restore with Apple."

Tags: itunes, ipad, downgrade

What doest `verify the restore with Apple` mean for me? What will be the effect when I perform such update?

What I am going to do?

Downgrade iPad to **iOS 8.4.1**. So far I downloaded `.ipsw` file, and then with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> I clicked **Restore iPad...** in iTunes Connect. What is gonna happen now?

Comment: My answer here has more information on this topic and some reading material for those interested in a deeper understanding: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/216416/18387

Answer (score 1):

In [this discussion from 2010 on apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2464494?tstart=0) it says this:

"I can't speak for Apple programmers. If you still have the 3.1.3 ipsw file on your computer it will reuse it and not download it again, but it will still go back to Apple's server to verify the copy that you have, presumably to verify that it has not been hacked."

If you google "verify the restore with apple" you will see it mentioned in a lot of jail breaking related posts. To me this suggests its somehow meant to prevent jail breaking. And perhaps thats what the post in the apple discussion meant by 'hacked'.

To me it also sort of sounds like something intended to prevent people from using stolen apple stuff.

Edit: in addition to what i said in the comments, and to give you an answer with some more finality: Backing up to firmware that you got from a third party *may* work fine. But theres no reason to believe that it will, other than your own personal perception of the place where you got it from.

Comment: But will I be able to install that software and working with it or not?

Comment: What specific software are you asking about?

Comment: Ipsw file with ios 8.4.1 version from iphonehacked.com or sth like that.

Comment: Verification generally refers to checking the "validity" of something, in this case it would seem that they must be be referring to the validity in terms of the firmware, and maybe the apps too. This will be harder to answer as apple can change the standards of validity at their own discretion, so what worked one year ago might not work today.

Comment: I am not aware of any public record of what firmware apple will permit, or the "correctness" of the firmware on iphonehacked.com. The implication, however, is that this step serves to prevent a user from backing up to a firmware that is somehow undesirable. id guess its looking for backups that may contain malicious software (which encompasses jail breaking (because for all apple knows there is something malicious on it)), or a security flaw (perhaps they identified a security flaw in an older version of ios (also apple probably worries about security flaws in jailbroken phones)).

Answer (score 1):

When iTunes says that it means that it is checking with the Apple servers if:

1. The ipsw is valid (if it wasn't modified).
2. If it is still signed by Apple (this prevents users from downgrading to less secure versions)

iOS 8.4.1 is no longer signed, meaning that there is no way to downgrade, the only signed iOS versions for now are iOS 9.1 and iOS 9.2 if you're in the beta program.

If you want to check this in the future, ipsw.me has a pretty good database on signed firmware versions for specific devices.